# Finding a solution to fill a void in an edge-to-edge planar tiling with a limited set of tiles

Tags: geometry, problem-solving, tiling

Given an edge-to-edge tiling consisting of a finite set of prototiles, if the tiling contains a void, is there a way to find a tiling that fills it?

For example, given a square and triangle as prototiles, this arrangement can be constructed:

[image: Example tiling]

Intuitively, there doesn't seem to be a solution. But is there a way to prove it? Or, if a solution is proven to exist, how would it be found?

The example given is quite simple, but a more complex tiling quickly becomes a challenge:

[image: Complex tiling]

(This second example is built from 14 prototiles, and has a solution.)

Comment: One can easily construct a few necessary conditions for a solution to exist. For example the area of the void has to be representable as a combination of the areas of the tiles. Additionally the angles of the void have to be representable as sums of angles of the tiles. Proving the exists a solution can probably only be done by exhibiting a solution.

Comment: Thanks, that’s helpful - do you know of a general field of study where these kinds of proofs would be researched?

Comment: No other thoughts on this question?

Answer (score 1):

To address the specific question in your first example: yes, it can be proven that there is no way to fill the void.

Consider one of the vertices of the "hole" which touches a square. There are $150$ degrees of angle that need to be filled; the only way to do this is to use one square and one triangle. The square will then end up touching one of the four-triangle vertices. But then this vertex will have a $30^\circ$ angle left to be filled, which is impossible with the given tiles:

[image: 1]

---

In general, you should expect this to be an extremely hard problem, probably as difficult as the general question of determining whether a tiling exists in a given region - the fact that the border is made up of tiles from your original set does not seem to make the analysis any easier.